# WPF MVVM - Disabled checkbox requires a setter on property binded to IsEnabled to work

Tags: wpf, checkbox, mvvm, data-binding

A coworker of mine just encountered some weird behaviour with binding in Wpf.

First of all here is what he wanted to achieve :

- Display a disabled checkbox (so the user can't set it by clicking on it)
- Bind this checkbox IsChecked to some bool values to notify the user that some filter is active or not.

In code the property looks like this :

**C#**

```
public bool IsFooBarFilterEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return _isFoo && _isBar;
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsFooBarFilterEnabled}" IsEnabled="False" />
```

Then whener he sets `_isFoo` or `_isBar` he calls `RaisePropertyChanged(()=>IsFooBarFilterEnabled);`

So far everything looks fine to me... but his code doesn't work.

We had to add an empty setter like this :

```
public bool IsFooBarFilterEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return _isFoo && _isBar;
    }
    set{}// that's not what i would call beautifull code
}
```

That's where my question is. If the checkbox is disabled, the setter on IsFooBarFilterEnabled should never be called. So why do have to create one to avoid crashes ? What is our mistake on this ?

Comment: if i understand you  correctly, you'll need to use one way binding e.g `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsFooBarFilterEnabled, Mode=OneWay}" IsEnabled="False" />` that way you won't need a setter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `Binding Mode` is set to `TwoWay`, which means that both the property and the component must be updated if the other is changed. Also, the `ComboBox` is `disabled` *now*, it doesn't mean it'll be disabled *always*.

You must either create the empty set (if you wish to continue with the `TwoWay` binding) or set the `Binding Mode` as `OneWay` (which means that the component should be updated when the property changes, but not the other way around)

Here's an example:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsFooBarFilterEnabled, Mode=OneWay}" IsEnabled="False" />
```